# Search for "word<>" and replace with "word=word1"

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file with the following information:

```
dog<>
cat<>
cow<>
bird<>
tiger<>
lion<>
puma<>
```

could it be possible to run a search & replace in notepad++ that would yield something like this:

```
dog=dog1
cat=cat1
cow=cow1
bird=bird1
tiger=tiger1
lion=lion1
puma=puma1
```

Comment: Question was good and so also the answer. But I feel we should construct the question `title` with more specification (not general) for better book keeping and searching.  Of course, I am not saying I always do this job right. Just some thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find:

```
^(.+)<>$
```

Replace with

```
\1=\11
```